# Function is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hi I'm a beginner in jsx and I'm facing I'm sure a simple bug but I'm unable to solve it
i've coded a simple delete function in my app js, and I'm stuck on this error.

here's my App.js file

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Essai from './Essai.js';
import AddEssai from './addEssai.js';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    essais : [
      {name : 'pek', age: 30, sexe : 'f', id:'1'},
      {name : 'plop', age: 31, sexe : 'fh', id:'2'},
      {name : 'pekkrure', age: 35, sexe : 'h', id:'3'}
    ]
  }
  
  deleteEssai = (id) =>{
    console.log('fonction ok')
  } 
    
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>My first react app</h1>
       
       <Essai essai ={this.state.essais}/>
       <AddEssai deleteEssai = {this.deleteEssai} addEssai = {this.addEssai} />
      </div>
   )
    };
}

export default App;
```

And here's my component

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Essai = (props) => {
    
    //console.log(this.props.age)
    const { essai } = props;
    const essaiList = essai.map( essai => {
        return(
            <div className= "essai" key = {essai.id}>
                <div>Name: {essai.name} </div>
                <div>Age: {essai.age} </div>
                <div>sexe: {essai.sexe} </div>
                <button onClick = {() => {deleteEssai(essai.id)}}>DELETE</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
    return(
        <div className = "essaiList">
            {essaiList};
        </div> 
    )
    
}
export default Essai
```

I always get this error

./src/Essai.js
  Line 13:43:  'deleteEssai' is not defined  no-undef

If someone could take a minute to guide me that would be very nice thank you!!!

Comment: Please keep in mind if one of the answers work for you can Mark them as answer by using the grey mark (tick) icon. For more information, you can read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

Actually **you are using `deleteEssai` in your child component, but never pass it as a prop to it**, so it will throw an undefined error since there is no such a thing there. You just need to pass it as a prop to your child component.

Like this:

```html
<Essai deleteEssai={this.deleteEssai} essai={this.state.essais}/>
```

And **then you need to destructure in your child component** as well.

```js
const { essai, deleteEssai } = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things you should look at:

1. You are not passing the `deleteEssai` as a prop to this component `<Essai />` in you `<App />`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Essai from './Essai.js';
import AddEssai from './addEssai.js';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    essais : [
      {name : 'pek', age: 30, sexe : 'f', id:'1'},
      {name : 'plop', age: 31, sexe : 'fh', id:'2'},
      {name : 'pekkrure', age: 35, sexe : 'h', id:'3'}
    ]
  }

  deleteEssai = (id) =>{
    console.log('fonction ok')
  } 


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>My first react app</h1>

       {/*                              ->>> Pass here*/}
       <Essai essai={this.state.essais} deleteEssai={this.deleteEssai}/>
       <AddEssai deleteEssai = {this.deleteEssai} addEssai = {this.addEssai} />
      </div>
   )
    };
}

export default App;
```

2. Then in `<Essai />` you use it from prop:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Essai = (props) => {

    //console.log(this.props.age)
    // Desctructure 'deleteEssai' from props
    const { essai, deleteEssai } = props;
    const essaiList = essai.map( essai => {
        return(
            <div className= "essai" key = {essai.id}>
                <div>Name: {essai.name} </div>
                <div>Age: {essai.age} </div>
                <div>sexe: {essai.sexe} </div>
                <button onClick = {() => {deleteEssai(essai.id)}}>DELETE</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
    return(
        <div className = "essaiList">
            {essaiList};
        </div> 
    )

}
export default Essai;
```